# Debugging Azure Functions with local Cosmos DB Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am attempting to test an Azure Function (written in C# on VS 2019 Community, triggered with an HTTP trigger) running against a local Cosmos DB Emulator. When my code attempts to communicate with the emulator, it appears to time out, and gives me an exception.

The relevant code snippet:

```
CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(storageURL, authKeyString);

try
{
   Database oldDB = client.GetDatabase(dbName);
   DatabaseResponse dbResp = await oldDB.DeleteAsync();
}
```

My input variables:

```
storageURL  "http://localhost:8081"
authKeyString   "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=="
```

On the call to GetDatabase(), the code waits for a good long while and throws an exception:

```
{"The operation was canceled."}
    CancellationToken: IsCancellationRequested = true
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233029
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request."}
    Message: "The operation was canceled."
    Source: "System.Net.Http"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<SendAsyncCore>d__61.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync>d__40.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<SendWithRetryAsync>d__39.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.Exce
ptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.DocumentClient.HttpRequestMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.C
ompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__62.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.GatewayAccountReader.<GetDatabaseAccountAsync>d__8.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Routing.GlobalEndpointManager.<GetDatabaseAccountFromAnyLocationsAsync>d__16.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuc
cess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.GatewayAccountReader.<InitializeReaderAsync>d__9.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosAccountServiceConfiguration.<InitializeAsync>d__36.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.DocumentClient.<InitializeGatewayConfigurationReaderAsync>d__309.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System
.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.DocumentClient.<GetInitializationTaskAsync>d__103.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.DocumentClient.<EnsureValidClientAsync>d__163.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RequestInvokerHandler.<EnsureValidClientAsync>d__9.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.Exceptio
nDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RequestInvokerHandler.<SendAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RequestInvokerHandler.<SendAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactory.<ProcessMessageAsync>d__16`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.
ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Leaderboard_CosmosDB.Leaderboard_CosmosDB.<CreateDB>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\\Users\\Matthew\\source\\repos\\Leaderboard_CosmosDB\\Leaderboard_CosmosDB\\Leaderboard_CosmosDB.cs:line 89"
    TargetSite: {Void MoveNext()}
    Task: null
```

If I replace the storageURL and authKeyString in my local.settings.json file with a URL and key from a Cosmos DB instance running in Azure, the code works fine. Of course, I'd prefer to debug locally (and cost-free).

The Cosmos Emulator is running on the same machine as the function debugger. I am able to create a new database/container in the emulator using Data Explorer in a web browser running on the same machine.

This has happened to me on 2 different machines. It happens whether the Windows firewall is on or off.

What's the secret sauce to get a locally-debugged Azure function to connect to a local instance of Cosmos DB emulator?

EDIT: Others have asked for the full code of the function experiencing the problem. Here you are:

```
[FunctionName("CreateDB")]
        public static async Task<string> CreateDB(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log,
            ExecutionContext context)
        {

            string storageURL = "http://localhost:8081";
            string authKeyString = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";
            string dbName = "testDB";
            string containerName = "testContainer");
            string partitionKeyPath = "/partition");
            CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(storageURL, authKeyString);

            try
            {
                Database oldDB = client.GetDatabase(dbName);
                DatabaseResponse dbResp = await oldDB.DeleteAsync(); //Error is here
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (!ex.Message.Contains("Resource Not Found"))
                {
                    return ("Error deleting old database: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }


            try
            {
                DatabaseResponse dbresp = await client.CreateDatabaseAsync(dbName);
                ContainerResponse cresp = await dbresp.Database.CreateContainerAsync(new ContainerProperties(containerName, partitionKeyPath));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return (ex.Message);
            }



            return ("OK");
        }
```

Comment: have you tried to leave out the `http://`? https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#authenticating-requests

Comment: I was very hopeful when I saw this, but when I try it I get an exception: "Only 'http' and 'https' schemes are allowed."

Comment: Can you share the Azure Function's code? Is the Emulator running on the same machine or in another or in a virtual machine?

Comment: Full code added to initial post as EDIT at the end.

Comment: Why `http` and not `https` as the Emulator documentation and the UI suggests? Also, please, do not create clients inside the Function execution code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#static-clients

Comment: I'll be damned. Moving from HTTP to HTTPS solved it. I had assumed that the client would reject the self-signed certificate (that I assume the emulator creates for HTTPS connections).

If you'll post this as a top-level response, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score -2):

Same environment, and I got a success.

1. [Install Azure Cosmos Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#installation)
2. Get endpoint and key from emulator page
   [image]
3. Create a sample console app

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string endpoint = "https://localhost:8081";
            string key = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";
            string databaseId = "TestDB";
            string containerId = "TestContainer";
            var client = new CosmosClient(endpoint, key);
            var db = client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseId).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Database;
            var container = db.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerId, "/partitionkey").GetAwaiter().GetResult().Container;
            var result = container.CreateItemAsync(new { id = Guid.NewGuid(), partitionkey = "A", content = "Test" }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

4. Result
   [image]

From the result, you can see that I can successfully connect to emulator and create item. Please check your steps to see if there is anything wrong.

Comment: This works for me as well. However, when debugging an Azure Function locally, I get the problems described in my initial post.